Lie's Second Theorem - Prove that $\Phi$ is indeed a homomorphism
I am working through the proof that a Lie algebra homomorphism $\phi:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{h}$ extends to a Lie group homomorphism $\Phi: G\rightarrow H$ if $G$ is simply connected, following Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction by Brian C. Hall. The author writes out most of the proof but leaves the actual proof that $\Phi$ is a homomorphism as an exercise.
Author's Proof
The proof takes a neighbourhood $V$ of $I \in G$ on which $\exp$ is a diffeomorphism, and defines $\Phi : V\rightarrow H$ by $\Phi(A) = \exp(\phi(\log A))$. $\Phi$ is extended to arbitrary $A \in G$ by considering a path $A(t)$ connecting $A$ to $I$ and a partition $0 = t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_m = 1$ of $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A(t_i)A(t_{i-1})^{-1} \in V$, and defining
$\Phi(A) = \Phi[A(t_i)A(t_{i-1})^{-1}]\ldots\Phi[A(t_2)A(t_{1})^{-1}]\Phi[A(t_1)]$.
The proof proceeds to show that $\Phi$ is well-defined independently of the partition and path. However, the proof that $\Phi$ is actually a homomorphism is left as an exercise.
Exercise
The author suggests considering paths $A(t)$, $B(t)$, and $C(t)$ with $C(t) = A(2t), t \in [0, 1/2]$ and $C(t) = AB(2t-1), t\in [1/2, 1]$ and a partition $t_0/2, \ldots t_m/2, 1/ + s_0/2, \ldots, 1/2 + s_M/2$, where the $t_i$ and $s_i$ form a valid partition for $A(t)$ and $B(t)$, and computing the various products needed to establish the homomorphism.
To illustrate my difficulty, we can consider the simplest case that $A, B \in V$ already and $AB$ might not be. (If $AB \in V$, then using BCH, one can show that $\Phi$ is a "local homomorphism" and that $\Phi(AB) = \Phi(A)\Phi(B)$. This is used to prove that the path is independent of partition). Then using the partition as given, we find that
$\Phi(C) = \Phi(ABA^{-1}) \Phi(A)$.
(in the general case, you get a bunch of factors of the form $\Phi(AB(s_i)A^{-1})$, so if I can solve the simple case the general case is done, too).
Using the local definition of $\Phi$, I get
$\Phi(ABA^{-1}) = \exp(\phi(\log(ABA^{-1}))
= \exp(\phi(A\log B A^{-1}))$
and now I'd really like to say that $\phi(A \log BA^{-1})$ = $\Phi(A)\phi(\log B)\Phi(A)^{-1}$, since $\phi$ is the Lie algebra homomorphism induced by $\Phi$, but I don't know how to justify this. In my book, the proof of this already assumes that $\Phi$ is a homomorphism, and I'm not sure how to alter the proof to work in this more limited case.
The author has shown that "$\Phi$ has the proper relation to $\phi$" by showing that
$\dfrac{d}{dt}\Phi(\exp (tX))|_{t=0} = \phi(X),$
but it's not really clear to me if I can use this, or the BCH, or anything else, to show what I want to show, or if that's even the appropriate proof strategy.
